# DAX query for DATEVALUE

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax

I have DAX Query and need to assign DATEVALUE to column in IF clause.

```
    Invoice_Date :=
IF (
    FactCustTrans[DOCUMENTDATE]=DATEVALUE ( "1/1/1900" ),
    FactCustTrans[TRANSDATE],
    FactCustTrans[DOCUMENTDATE]
)
```

Error is **The syntax for '=' is not correct**

Comment: What data type is `DOCUMENTDATE`?

Comment: It's DateTime .

Comment: Is this a calculated column or a measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the DATE function ( YYYY, MM, DD )

```
    Invoice_Date :=
IF (
    FactCustTrans[DOCUMENTDATE]= DATE ( 1900,1,1 ),
    FactCustTrans[TRANSDATE],
    FactCustTrans[DOCUMENTDATE]
)
```